# How to set --disable-web-security in PlayWright - Java

Tags: java, playwright

Is there any possibility to pass "`--disable-web-security`" parameter when opening a new web page, as we do in selenium.

Edit:

```
I was able to get it done by below code
     String[] chromiumArgs = {
                    "--disable-web-security",
                    "--no-sandbox",
                    "--start-maximized",
                    "--ignore-certificate-errors",// Additional options if needed
                    "--PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL"
    
            };
            browser = playwright.chromium().launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setHeadless(false).setArgs(Arrays.asList(chromiumArgs)));
```